# Windows Biometric Framework API

Tags: face-recognition, biometrics

I've read through the Windows documentation but I still have some grey zones:

- Is this api completely independent of the current Windows user ?
- Can I create/delete users independently of Windows users ?
- Is there a better solution for face authetification in Windows platform ?

Comment: I have the same answer, did you find any answers?